# Javascript: Non-blocking way to wait until a condition is true

Tags: javascript, sleep, wait

I have several ASP.NET UpdatePanels, each with an AsyncPostBackTrigger tied to the same button's serverside click event.  Since only one UpdatePanel can be doing its thing at a time, I use `.get_isInAsyncPostBack()` of the `PageRequestManager` to prevent a user from being able to access another part of the page until the async postback is complete.

Another part of this page needs to dynamically update multiple update panels consecutively.  Since the update panels use async triggers, calling `__doPostBack("<%=ButtonName.ClientID %>", 'PanelId');` fires asynchonously.  Because of this, it will quickly move along to the next iteration of the loop and try to update the next panel.  However, the second iteration fails because there is already another update panel doing an async postback.

Ideally, there would be a way to wait until `.get_isInAsyncPostBack()` returns false without blocking other client activity.

Research has lead me to a lot people with my problem, almost all of whom are advised to use `setTimeOut()`.  I do not thing this will work for me.  I don't want to wait for a specified amount of time before executing a function.  I simply want my Javascript to wait while another script is running, preferably wait until a specific condition is true.

I understand that many will probably want to suggest that I rethink my model.  It's actually not my model, but one that was handed to our development team that is currently a total mess under the hood.  Due to time contraints, rewriting the model is not an option.  The only option is to make this work.  I think that if I had a way to make the client code wait without blocking, my problem would be solved.

Comment: That's simply not how JavaScript works. It will execute all code synchronously. HTML5s cool new [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) might help, but for the rest you'll have no choice but to use `setTimeout` / `setInterval`.

Comment: Good question.i found it when i trying two write one.

Comment: Currently, maybe a better way of solving such issues would be to use web worker for waiting for server-side answer.

Answer (score 38):

There is no such functionality such as wait or sleep in javascript, since it would stop browser from responding.

In your case I would go with something similar to following:

```
function wait(){
  if (!condition){
    setTimeout(wait,100);
  } else {
    // CODE GOES IN HERE
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is supposed to work.  When I execute this code `setTimeout(function () { alert("waiting"); }, 5000); alert("donewaiting");`, "donewaiting" is alerted first, followed by "waiting" 5 second later.  What's the point of waiting if it's just going to move immediately to the next line of code?

Comment: the concept of set timeout is different, it does not stop the execution of code, but executes code after some time. There is NO WAY (at least good) of pausing the script. You will have to replace ... CODE GOES IN HERE ... with the logic should be executed after the condition is met

Comment: This 'polling' technique essentially runs the `wait` function every 100 ms until the `condition` becomes `true`. For your purposes, I would replace `condition` here with `.get_isInAsyncPostBack()` and `...CODE GOES IN HERE...` with the call to update the next panel, followed by a `wait` for the next panel. You'll want a new `wait()` function for each panel (e.g., `waitForPanel1()`, `waitForPanel2()`, etc.

Comment: How about javascript maximum call-stack size?

Comment: @pylover using `setTimeout` should not affect the call-stack because it doesn't execute the function again until after the current function has completed. It is possible to do it wrong. I'll add an answer to cover that.

Answer (score 14):

It's easy to make a mistake when calling `setTimeout` that will cause the JavaScript call stack to fill up. If your function has parameters, you need to pass those in at the end of the `setTimeout` parameter list like this:

```
function wait(param1, param2){
  if (!condition){
    setTimeout(wait, 100, param1, param2);
  } else {
    // CODE GOES IN HERE
  }
}
```

If you pass parameters or even include empty () after the name of the function, it will be executed immediately and fill up the stack.

```
// This is the wrong way to do it!    
function wait(param1, param2){
  if (!condition){
    setTimeout(wait(param1, param2), 100); // you'll get max call stack error if you do this!
  } else {
    // CODE GOES IN HERE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I needed to slow down a process and came up with a helpful little method.

```
const wait = (seconds) => 
   new Promise(resolve => 
      setTimeout(() => resolve(true), seconds * 1000)
   );
```

And you can use it like this.

```
const doWork = async() => {
   // After 3 seconds do something...
   await wait(3);
   console.log('work done');
}
```

Comment: This is a non blocking way to wait without the need of a recursive call. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

This function calls condFunc which should return true when condition is met. When that happens readyFunc is called. checkInterval sets checking rate in milliseconds

```
       var wait = function(condFunc, readyFunc, checkInterval) {
            var checkFunc = function() {
                if(condFunc()) {
                    readyFunc(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    setTimeout(checkFunc, checkInterval);
                }
            };
            checkFunc();
        };
```

Usage:

```
       wait(
            function() { return new Date().getSeconds() == 10; }, 
            function() { console.log("Done"); },
            100
        );
```

prints "Done" when current time is 10 seconds after minute