# Infinite loop checker crashes - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So I wrote this short code for a small project of mine, here's the code:

```
while(true){


if(PremiumExchange.data.stock["wood"]>=64){

var x = PremiumExchange.data.stock["wood"];
document.getElementsByName('buy_wood')[0].value = x;
document.getElementsByClassName('btn float_right btn-premium-exchange-buy')[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName('btn evt-confirm-btn btn-confirm-yes')[0].click();

}
}
```

Essentially "`PremiumExchange.data.stock["wood"]`" updates randomly after sometimes on the webpage. I'd like to set my code up so it keeps an eye on it and then does what I instructed it to.

Problem is, if I use an infinite loop, it hangs. Is there a way around this? Perhaps a timer of some sort?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I also tried

```
function wait(){
  if (!(PremiumExchange.data.stock["wood"]>=64)){
    setTimeout(wait,500);
  } else {
    var x = PremiumExchange.data.stock["wood"];
document.getElementsByName('buy_wood')[0].value = x;
document.getElementsByClassName('btn float_right btn-premium-exchange-buy')[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName('btn evt-confirm-btn btn-confirm-yes')[0].click();
  }
}
```

But it doesn't appear to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Non-blocking way to wait until a condition is true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841568/javascript-non-blocking-way-to-wait-until-a-condition-is-true)

Comment: Could you try `setInterval`?

Comment: @StardustGogeta I'm a novice, I've no idea how to use that. Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Constantine See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function test() {
  if (document.getElementById("test").value) {
    console.log("Success!");
    clearInterval(int);
  }
}

var int = setInterval(test,0);
```

```html
<input id="test"></input>
```

This is an example of setting a test without causing a hang.

Optionally, `clearInterval` is included to make it only execute once.

Comment: Thank you very much