# Loop in chrome extension javascript is making the page not loading

Tags: javascript, loops, google-chrome

i just wanted to make a condition before the script runs so i decided to run this loop before my code, however the website does not want to load with it :

```
s =document.documentElement.innerText.split(",")[5]
while (s != " 2021 - June 25"){
    s =document.documentElement.innerText.split(",")[5]
}
```

it checks if it has correct string so it can run the full script. I made this because the website has dynamic content and load in 2 times. Hope you understand me.
website is : https://www.nike.com/events-registration/event?id=1618516799261

thank you.

Comment: On worst case if you really need to check this use setTimeout instead of a for loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Non-blocking way to wait until a condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841568/javascript-non-blocking-way-to-wait-until-a-condition-is-true)

Comment: It looks like what you are trying to do is causing an infinite loop. The while condition will always be true and this will keep on happening. Nothing else will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following technique :

1. Set an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to check for an image DOM element and add an event listener to it.
2. The event listener should wait for the image to load, and then you can perform your actions.

We choose images because they load slow. Try to find out the class/id(should not be dynamic) of any image.

```
var checkInterval = setInterval(()=>{
if(document.querySelector('.slowImageClass')!=null){
document.querySelector('.slowImageClass').addEventListener('load', () => {
   clearInterval(checkInterval ); //To stop the loop
   //Your actions

});
}
},300  /**  time in milliseconds        **/);
```

[Load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event works on only a few DOM Element types. Image is one of them.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However it says null until they appear on screen? can't they appear in the html code but not on screen? Can i do the same with another class like a string or so?

Comment: Load is for images to load. When they are in the DOM(HTML code), then the if condition becomes true. When the images are actually loaded then the event handler is executed.

Comment: ok thank you, in the website im trying to use it when i inspect element of the picture and take the class name. document.querySelector('hero-image--image-wrapper ng-scope') is returning me (in the console) always null, is that normal?

Comment: Dont forget the '.' in front of classes. If it is an id it is '#'

Comment: true i forgot it, document.querySelector('.hero-image--image animated fadeIn ng-scope') returns null and it is a class of the image. The image is loaded though, weird.

Comment: For multiple classes you will have to use . like -> document.querySelector('.hero-image--image.animated');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233679/discussion-between-mehditation-and-tushar-shahi).